# The data didn't show up after calling 'deleteRow' method

Tags: uitableview

[image]

The problem like this in this gif picture, when I called 'deleteRow'
method the other row which should show some data became blank, I did nothing to that row,this picture show what I do here:

[image]

(forgive my poor english )

I wanna know why this row been refreshed after I update the table view.

Comment: In the gif it looks like you are deleting the wrong cell.

Comment: @dasdom Thank you, you are right, I have figured it out.  I made a stupid mistake.